# Getting polygons out of .shp

Tags: shapefile, vector-grid

I have a shapefile with lines. In the attributes of the line shapefile I have known coordinates.

I want to get polygons out of these points which reach to the next line.
As a goal I want a grid out of polygons. Each polygon should contact each neighbour and should have the same ID with the known coordinate.

[image]

[image: here are the coordinates in the attribute tabel]

[image]

Comment: Could you upload a screenshot where your points are displayed, too?

Comment: So the coordinates are on the lines? If you still want an answer, can you provide sample data? It's easier to answer, otherwise I first have to create own data that might not correspond to your case. By the way: on the screenshot, the yellow lines are barely visible. Next time choose a color with a strong contrast to the background.

Answer (score 0):

I found two sources that may interest you. You can also create a delimited text file, but it may be laborious.

https://archeomatic.wordpress.com/2012/06/21/qgis-analyse-par-maille-1-creer-un-maille-carree-avec-loutil-grille-vecteur/

In french

https://gis.stackovernet.com/fr/q/34200

In english

Comment: It is always recommended to include a detailed answer rather than a link-only answer. This way, if the link dies, the answer still lives on.